# Problems with queries in NodeJS (same result with diferents queries)

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have this query in NodeJS:
*File: lists.js*

```
module.exports.list = (source, fields, orderBy, queryData, start, limit, callback) => {
    db.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }

        let limitQuery = '';
        let limitValues = [];
        if (limit) {
            limitQuery = ' LIMIT ?';
            limitValues.push(limit);

            if (start) {
                limitQuery += ' OFFSET ?';
                limitValues.push(start);
            }
        }

        let whereClause = '';
        let whereValues = [];

        if (queryData) {
            whereClause = ' WHERE ' + queryData.where;
            whereValues = queryData.values;
        }

        connection.query('SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ' + fields.join(', ') + ' FROM ' + source + whereClause + ' ORDER BY ' + orderBy + ' DESC' + limitQuery, whereValues.concat(limitValues), (err, rows) => {
            if (err) {
                connection.release();
                return callback(err);
            }
            console.log(rows);
            connection.query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS total', (err, total) => {
                connection.release();
                if (err) {
                    return callback(err);
                }
                return callback(null, rows, total && total[0] && total[0].total);
            });
        });
    });
};
```

And i have this in *table-helpers.js*:

```
module.exports.filter = (request, parent, callback) => {
    tableHelpers.filter('lists', ['*'], request, ['#', 'name', 'cid', 'subscribers', 'description'], ['name'], 'name ASC', null, callback);
};
```

The problem is that the view keeps showing me the same even if I change the query. I can not find where the problem is.

I hope you can help me, thanks in advance

Comment: What do you call you `view`? Your browser?

Comment: Yes, but If I try to see the result of the query by console it does not show anything